# Insert Sheet Name Beginning with 0 into Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to give a cell the name for my sheet (064149107). The name cannot be changed and there are many sheets in the workbook.

My code works fine except when the name of my sheet begins by 0.

For example, instead of 064149107 i get 64149107 in the cell.

As i'm doing a vlookup after this, i have no match found and an error 2042.

here is my code :

```
sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2) = sht.Name
```

i tried also this :

```
            If Left(sht.Name, 1) = "0" Then 'règle le probleme d'un sheet name commencant par 0
            sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2) = "0" & sht.Name
            Else
            sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2) = sht.Name
            End If
```

But i didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing Excel is converting the string to a number.  Just save the value as a string.

Comment: Note that you don't really need VBA to put the sheet name in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will put a tick `'` character in front of the Name.

```
sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2).Value = chr(39) & sht.Name
```

Alternatively, you could set the format of the cell to `Text` first:

```
sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2).Value = sht.Name
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect

Answer (score 0):

Could you not try something like:

```
sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2).Value = "'" & sht.Name
```

I've not tried it but by explicitly making it text I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the format of the cell, via the ribbon "Home", in the "Number" tab, change "General" by "Text". Then run the code again.

But note that you don't need VBA to fill in the sheet name in a cell. This can be done with an in-cell formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```